# CakePHP : access AppController from Model

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.0 and I need to be able to use an object (Logger) everywhere in my applications (from controllers and models).

This object is created in the AppController like this :

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('Logger', 'Lib');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Logger = new Logger(APP.'webroot/logs');
    }
}
?>
```

This works fine for controllers, I can use this object from every controller of the application, this way : `$this->Logger->...`

But obviously, it doesn't work from a model (because models don't extends AppController).

So I need :

1. to know how to access a controller attribute (Logger) from a model
2. or another way to achieve this (creating a global object accessible everywhere), not using `AppController->beforeFilter()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To put it bluntly what you are doing is absolute crap. Read the chapter on [logging](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html) on the cakephp manual and see how to configure log streams and how to write to them.